# Should I go to New-Zealand on November instead of December just to make it to the Milford track?

Tags: weather, new-zealand

(I know this is subjective, but I'm really at loss with all the confliciting advice I get from my friends... help me stack-exchange! :) )

Hey, I'm planning on doing 2 months trekking in New-Zealand. Original plan was Dec-Jan, for the best weather. However, the *only* date I was able to reserve for the Milford Sound track is Nov/7th.

WDYS? should I go on Nov-Dec and risk crummier weather just so I won't miss the Milford experience? OR is it just another amazing track among many others and aiming for the best chance of good weather is more important.

background: I have no other work/family constraints, and I'm really into outdoors trekking.

Comment: This is purely asking for opinions, I'm afraid - and at the end of the day that doesn't work on Stack Exchange. Some folks would say yes, some no - still won't help you. Have a look at [ask] for guidance questions that can work here.

Comment: Ask the NZ Dept of Conservation. They'll know what's up, and there are many amazing great walk tracks that would not be a disappointing alternative.

Comment: Milford track weather statistics - you will have the same chance of rain (15 days of the month) in November or Jan. You will  get 30% more rain in Jan and have higher humidity, more sandflys (Sparrow sized insects that suck your blood dry) and more people. Jan is 4 degrees warmer - i.e. - All this in the background of nearly 7 meters annual rainfall.

Comment: Milford is a spectacular track, but its far from the most spectacular in New Zealand. If you come in November, stick the  relatively safety of the Great Walks unless you really know your stuff.